# Configure Google Cloud API Gateway for optional Authenticated with JWT, and unauthenticated?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, graphql, google-cloud-functions, auth0, google-api-gateway

I am trying to set up a GraqphQL Server, on Cloud Functions, and I want to set up an API Gateway to handle authentication with auth0 and jwt....

I have it working from the tutorial, the problem is it always requires a JWT token, where as I want some GraphQL queries to be available publicly, and if the user signs in they get more access...

From my understanding the way you do this is by using two authentications in the security settings, where one is the JWT and one is empty, however the API Gateway seems to always want the JWT token... Here is my open API spec, maybe someone has an idea?

```
swagger: '2.0'
info:
  title: <redacted>-graphql-api
  description: Basic GraphQL Open APISchema
  version: 1.0.0
schemes:
  - https
produces:
  - application/json
securityDefinitions:
  auth0_jwk:
    authorizationUrl: "<redacted>"
    flow: "implicit"
    type: "oauth2"
    # Replace YOUR-ACCOUNT-NAME with your Auth0 account name.
    x-google-issuer: "<redacted>"
    x-google-jwks_uri: "<redacted>"
    # Optional. Replace YOUR-CLIENT-ID with your client ID
    x-google-audiences: "<redacted>"
paths:
  /:
    post:
      summary: GraphQL endpoint
      operationId: gql
      x-google-backend:
        address: <redacted>  # App URL/endpoint
      responses:
        '200':
          description: A successful response
          schema:
            type: object
      security:
        - {}
        - auth0_jwk: []
    get:
      summary: GraphQL Playground
      operationId: playground
      x-google-backend:
        address: <redacted>  # App URL/endpoint
      responses:
        '200':
          description: A successful response
          schema:
            type: string
```

Comment: Issue tracker linked on this question: https://issuetracker.google.com/186604016